# read project directory to get properties file in java web application

Tags: java

Am trying to ready properties file which is presented in my project directory `src/test/resources/properties/api/`. But this way is not working and its give me file not found exception.

Please find my code below :

```
public Properties extractProperties() throws IOException {
        InputStream configReader= null;
        String env = getProperty("tuf.environment");
        try {
            configReader = new FileInputStream(new File("src/test/resources/properties/api/"+env+".properties")); // throwing exception
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        prop.load(configReader);
        return prop;
    }
```

Comment: That path isn't available as that is the root of the classpath nor will you be able to load files from inside a jar/war like this as it isn't a file ( a `File` is physical resource). So you have to load if from `/properties/api/` as the root and use a stream and not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your path you are using either Maven or Gradle as it looks like the default structure used by them. Which means `src/test/resources` points to the root of the classpath, so there is no `src/test/resources`. (The same applies to `src/main/resources` as well!).

So if you want to load it yuo would need to remove the `src/test/resources` part of the loading.

Next if this is run from a packaged application loading a `File` won't work as it isn't a `File`. The `File` needs to be a physical file on the filesystem and not inside an archive.

Taking all that into account you should be able to load the properties using the following

```
public Properties extractProperties() throws IOException {
  String env = getProperty("tuf.environment");
  String resource = "/properties/api/"+env+".properties";   

  try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource)) {
     prop.load(in);
     return prop;
   }
}
```

Comment: Am trying to print after `prop.load(in)` like this `System.out.println("Properties -->"+prop.getProperty("contentRoot"));` but am getting null error. Am having `contentRoot` in my properties file.

Comment: do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it the following way. Please note that the `extractProperties()` method will return an empty `Properties` object if the file was not found. Please also note the `try-with-resources` statement which will auto-close the `InputStream`.

```
public Properties extractProperties() throws IOException {
    String env = getProperty("tuf.environment");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try (InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/api/" + env + ".properties")) {
        prop.load(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
public Properties extractProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties prop=new Properties();
    String env = getProperty("tuf.environment");
    String mappingFileName = "/properties/api/" + env+ ".properties";
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + mappingFileName);
    try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedInputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        prop.load(bufferedInputStream);
                } catch IOException ie) {
                    //handle exception
                }
    return prop;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably `env` is not what you think it is. Why not list all files in that directory?
You can print with https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)
With the relevant directory:

```
Path apiDir = Paths.get("src/test/resources/properties/api/");
```